# How to generate an array/list from an output using .split() in Python 2.6

Tags: python, arrays

I just started picking up Python (2.X) and here I'm trying to "isolate" useful data set from a file so that I can do calculation.

I get to print out lines of data (numbers) by splitting the dictionary like this:

```
for n in lines:
    lx=n.split()[3]
    print lx
```

I would get the data set that I need from the index #3 of a dictionary. In terms of the output, it would be like this after executing the script:

```
1129.805
1291.123
2132.193
1239.182
1513.452
1287.783
[user@emach] $
```

but then I want to make them into a list or an array

```
l=[1129.805, 1291.123, 2132.193, 1239.182, 1513.452, 1287.783]
print l
[1129.805, 1291.123, 2132.193, 1239.182, 1513.452, 1287.783]
```

so that I can calculate this set of numbers (that is more than just 6 numbers). I know that I can use `sum()` , `len()` and other basic built-in math functions for calculation. I try to keep it very simple without using itertools, which I saw in a lot of posts here specifically for getting sum or average of a list.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This is what I have:

```
f=open("1FKA.pdb",'r')
lines=f.readlines()
f.close()

for n in lines:
        lx=[]
        lxx=[]
        if n[:4]=="ATOM":
                lx=n.split()[3]
                lxx=[float(n.split()[3]) for n in lines]
                print lx
                print lxx

Traceback (most recent call last):
lxx=[float(n.split()[3]) for n in lines]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `[n.split()[3] for n in lines]`

Comment: @devnull errr, you beat me by 28secs ;P

Comment: I may have did it incorrectly, but if I use `list.append()` I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`.

If I do `[n.split()[3] for n in lines]' I get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
[n.split()[3] for n in lines]
```

If `n.split()[3]` gives you a string, try:

```
[float(n.split()[3]) for n in lines]
```

### EDIT:

You also need to filter lines starting with "ATOM" in list comprehension, don't use that nested loop:

```
[float(n.split()[3]) for n in lines if n[:4]=="ATOM"]  #or n.startswith("ATOM") instead of n[:4]=="ATOM"
```

Or even:

```
[float(n.split()[3]) for n in lines if n.startswith("ATOM") and len(n.split())>3]
```

Comment: I still get that `IndexError: list index out of range`. :[

My data set will generate +3000 numbers, if that helps.

I'll also have to repeat this small part of the script 2 more times so that I can generate 3 arrays from the same file (that was opened (and close) at the beginning) to do 3 independent calculations.

Comment: @user3369861 do you mind posting the exact code and error tracebacks in your question spec?

Comment: @Madeon Why are you iterating the `lines` on every iteration of `lines` itself?

Comment: @thefourtheye I was trying to use list comprehension (something just suggested by zhangxaochen above) in the forloop under the `if` condition.

Comment: @Madeon I'm not suggesting you nest the loop. I guess there are some lines of length less than 4 words, so check your file.

Comment: @Madeon You can use just his suggestion, or you can simply change your code like this `[float(n.split()[3]) for n in lines if n[:4]=="ATOM"]` Just use this code instead of your entire for loop section.

Comment: @zhangxaochen Please filter the lines which start with `ATOM` in the comprehension and be done with it :)

Comment: @zhangxaochen +1 But can we somehow use [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)? ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen and thefortheye Thank you so much!

Comment: @Madeon np, glad to help ;P